# How to dynamically update API data in flask web app using ajax

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, flask

I have a web app that shows cryptocurrency prices/market cap/etc. The data is shown in a bootstrap table.
The problem I have is I would like to dynamically update, let's say, the prices of cryptocurrencies with ajax. I tried to update the prices with update.js every 15 seconds the prices should update.
The data is fetched but ajax won't update the prices.

index.html tbody:

```
<tbody>
  {% for crypto in cryptos: %}
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">{{ crypto.cmc_rank }}</th>
      <td><span class="info">Kryptowaluta: </span><span class="bigger">{{ crypto.name }}</span></div>  | <span class="gray">{{ crypto.symbol }}</span></td>
      <td><span class="info">Kurs: </span><div id="update-zl">{{ "{:,.2f}".format(crypto.quote.PLN.price)  }}</div> <span> zł</span></td>
      <td><span class="info">Zmiana % (24h): </span><span class="td bigger">{{ "{:,.4f}".format(crypto.quote.PLN.percent_change_24h) }}</span> <span>%</span></td>
      <td><span class="info">Kapitalizacja: </span>{{ "{:,.2f}".format(crypto.quote.PLN.market_cap) }}<span> zł</span></td>
      <td><span class="info">Wolumen (24h): </span>{{ "{:,.2f}".format(crypto.quote.PLN.volume_24h) }}<span> zł</span></td>
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
```

update.js

```
$(function(){
window.setInterval(function(){
    updateZl()
}, 15000)

function updateZl(){
$.ajax({
    url:"/update-zl",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
        $(updatezl).replaceWith(data)
    }
});
```

main.py

```
@app.route('/update-zl', methods=['GET'])
def updatezl():
    response = requests.get(url=ENDPOINT, params=parameters, headers=headers)
    data = response.json()
    crypto_data = data["data"]
    return render_template("update-zl.html", cryptos=crypto_data)
```

update_zl.html

```
{% for crypto in cryptos: %}
    <div id="update-zl">{{ "{:,.2f}".format(crypto.quote.PLN.price)  }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hi, what is `updatezl` in your code ?